# ComboBoxItem background rainbowRGB color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors

Folks:
I want to set the background color of a ComboBoxItem to be RainbowRGB:

[image: RainbowRGB]

and this is my current xaml code. I prefer to do it in xaml code:

```
           <ComboBoxItem>
                <Label Content=""
                       Background="RainbowRGB"
                       Width="180"
                       Margin="3" />
            </ComboBoxItem>
```

Anyone can give some pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Use Expression Blend to use Gradient Brush and to set colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <Label Content="blah">
        <Label.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.17"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.33"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.67"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Indigo" Offset="0.83"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Violet" Offset="1.0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Label.Background>
    </Label.Background>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use expression blend for this.using Eyedropper you can achieve this.watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZMUF6KYW18)

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <Label Height="75"  Width="405" Margin="3" >
        <Label.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.989,0.419" StartPoint="-0.001,0.446">
                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF000D22" Offset="0.002"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF051933" Offset="0.03"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF270437" Offset="0.035"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF110051" Offset="0.059"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF37005B" Offset="0.067"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF100074" Offset="0.084"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF4E0097" Offset="0.096"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8200FF" Offset="0.133"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF7600FF" Offset="0.197"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF4500FF" Offset="0.242"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1307FF" Offset="0.254"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0232FF" Offset="0.259"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF007AFF" Offset="0.279"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00F6F3" Offset="0.338"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00FF7B" Offset="0.481"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00FF47" Offset="0.507"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00FF0C" Offset="0.514"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF40FF00" Offset="0.521"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA1FF00" Offset="0.546"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF3FE00" Offset="0.576"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF2500" Offset="0.697"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0104" Offset="0.704"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0036" Offset="0.729"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF004D" Offset="0.805"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8F0031" Offset="0.879"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF790019" Offset="0.891"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF770026" Offset="0.901"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF5D0005" Offset="0.914"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF640021" Offset="0.921"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF54001A" Offset="0.933"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF400000" Offset="0.941"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF400000" Offset="0.956"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3B001C" Offset="0.965"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Label.Background>
    </Label>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

**Result**

[image]

Using viewbox you can use for different height and width

```
   <Viewbox Width="180" Height="40">
        <Label Height="75"  Width="405" Margin="3" >
            <Label.Background>
                -------------------
            </Label.Background>
        </Label>
    </Viewbox>
```